# BIC Instruction

Tags: assembly, arm

Hello I just have a basic question on some bit clearing in Assembly. Here is what I am trying below.

```
MOV R0, #OxFFFFFFFF   ;Load R0 with the HEX Values FFFFFFFF
BIC R0, R0, #0xBF    ;This should set bit 7 from my understanding as B is 1011 in hex
```

When performing the above it places the following value into R0 (0xFFFFFF4F) I wonder why this is?

If i do this bit clear it puts the value 0xFFFFFFBF

```
MOV R0, #OxFFFFFFFF   ;Load R0 with the HEX Values FFFFFFFF
BIC R0, R0, #00000000000000000000000001000000b
```

Can anyone help me understand these results?

Comment: sorry this is kind of unrelated but can BIC be written in C?

Comment: @chaitanya.varanasi: It's just AND with the inverse, like `x &= ~0xBF`.  That's why it's called Bit Clear - clear only the set bits in the mask.

Answer (score 9):

I find it interesting that the assembler (gas) lets you try to mov with more than 8 significant bits without error...it just encodes a mvn for you.

```
d6008030 <TESTFUN>:
d6008030:   e3e00000    mvn r0, #0
d6008034:   e3c000bf    bic r0, r0, #191    ; 0xbf
d6008038:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

I get 0xFFFFFF40 which is the expected answer.

If you want to set bit 7, then

```
orr r0,r0,#0x80 ;@ (corrected from 0x70)
```

Or did you mean you wanted to set bit 6

```
orr r0,r0,#0x40
```

if you wanted to strip off all of the bits except bit 6, leaving only bit 6 set.

```
and r0,r0,#0x40
```

If you want to leave all but bit 6 set (clear bit 6) (bic=bit clear)

```
bic r0,r0,#0x40
```

Or were you trying to do this

```
mov r0,#0xFFFFFFFF ;@ this is an interesting shortcut
mov r1,#0xFFFFFFBF ;@ might as well keep using it
bic r0,r0,r1
```

which gives 0x00000040, which is the same as

```
mov r0,#0xFFFFFFFF ;@ this is an interesting shortcut
and r0,r0,#0x40
```

except the latter uses less instructions and registers

EDIT

r0,r1,r2, arm tag, etc indicate this is an armv7-a or older question not aarch64 (x0, w0, w1, etc).

but you can see if the compiler will help you figure out what instructions are available for your architecture (arm or other).

```
unsigned int fun1(unsigned int x)
{
    return (x&(~6));
}
unsigned long long fun2(unsigned long long x)
{
    return (x&(~6));
}
```

armv4t - armv7a

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   e3c00006    bic r0, r0, #6
   4:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000008 <fun2>:
   8:   e3c00006    bic r0, r0, #6
   c:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

all thumb variants

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   2306        movs    r3, #6
   2:   4398        bics    r0, r3
   4:   4770        bx  lr
   6:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

00000008 <fun2>:
   8:   2306        movs    r3, #6
   a:   4398        bics    r0, r3
   c:   4770        bx  lr
   e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)
```

armv7-m (not armv6-m though, some armv8-m but not all)

```
00000000 <fun1>:
   0:   f020 0006   bic.w   r0, r0, #6
   4:   4770        bx  lr
   6:   bf00        nop

00000008 <fun2>:
   8:   f020 0006   bic.w   r0, r0, #6
   c:   4770        bx  lr
   e:   bf00        nop
```

aarch64 armv8-a

```
0000000000000000 <fun1>:
   0:   121d7400    and w0, w0, #0xfffffff9
   4:   d65f03c0    ret
   8:   d503201f    nop
   c:   d503201f    nop

0000000000000010 <fun2>:
  10:   927df400    and x0, x0, #0xfffffffffffffff9
  14:   d65f03c0    ret
```

Comment: Might be worth noting that (at least on aarch64) the encoding for `bic <xd>, <xn>, <imm>` does not exist. GAS, for example, will alias this instruction to an `and x0, x0, #0xffffffffffffffbf`.

Comment: Perhaps so. But I came here when I searched generally about `bic`. I was just making a note for anyone who comes here along a similar path. Your answer is generic enough that it still applies to arm64. I just realized that there was no such encoding for `bic` on arm64 is all. I didn't check to see if armv7 assemblers also aliased this use or if it actually existed then.

Answer (score 5):

I think you will see it better if you think about what BIC means/does: BIC Rd, Rn stands for "Rd AND NOT Rn".

So, with your last example:

```
Rn = 00000000000000000000000001000000b = 0x40
NOT Rn = 0xFFFFFFBF = 11111111111111111111111110111111b
Rd = 0xFFFFFFFF = 11111111111111111111111111111111b
Rd AND NOT Rn = 0xFFFFFFFBF = 11111111111111111111111110111111b
```

So, with BIC Rd, #0x40 you are clearing bit number 7 of Rd. Same thinking applies to your former example.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I test the cases with arm-none-eabi-gcc 4.8.2 on Arduino Due, but the first case is different.

```
// the results is 0xffffff40, but not 0xffffff4f
mov r2, #0xffffffff
bic r2, r2, #0xbf
```

The other case is the same.

So the result of the first case is clear just as @Fernando explained above.

```
operand2 = 0xbf
NOT operand2 = 0xffffff40
r2 = 0xffffffff
r2 AND NOT operand2 = 0xffffff40
```

The **BIC** (Bit Clear) instruction performs an AND operation on the bits in Rn with the complements of the corresponding bits in the value of Operand2. You can see it [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.ddi0337h/CHDDIGAC.html).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good at arm instructions but this instruction in your code

```
BIC R0, R0, #0xBF
```

#0xBF is #0b10111111, so I think it is clearing bits 0~6, and bit 8 of R0.
BIC is bit clearing instruction. To clear bit 7, you can do (set the bit position to 1 if you want to clear the bit)

```
BIC R0, R0, #0b01000000  ; or
BIC R0, R0, #0x40
```

I don't think you can 'set' a bit using BIC instruction. BIC is for 'clear'.

Comment: Right, `BIC dst, src` is simply `dst &= ~src`, an AND with an inverted immediate.  This can't set bits, only clear.